# $K_1 K_2$ is equal to $F(a_1,... ,a_n,b_1,... ,b_m)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

If $K_1 = F(a_1,..., a_n)$ and $K_2 = F(b_1,..., b_m)$.

**Claim:** Composite $K_1 K_2$ is equal to $F(a_1,... ,a_n,b_1,... ,b_m)$.

What we have to prove here is unclear to me.

$K_1 K_2 = F(a_1,..., a_n)(b_1,..., b_m) = F(a_1,..., a_n,b_1)(b_2,..., b_m) = ... \\ = F(a_1,..., a_n,b_1,..., b_{m-1})(b_m) =F(a_1,... ,a_n,b_1,... ,b_m). $

Hints to the problem are welcome. Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The composite $K_1K_2$ is the smallest field which contains $K_1$ and $K_2$. First, prove $F(a_1,\ldots,a_n,b_1,\ldots,b_m)$ contains $K_1$ and $K_2$. Then, take an arbitrary field $F$ containing both $K_1$ and $K_2$ and prove that $ F(a_1,\ldots,a_n,b_1,\ldots,b_m) \subset F$.

Comment: proving both the facts is trivial...\

Comment: Of course, but thats the proof.

Comment: ok...then I am done...the fact was so easy....I thought If I am missing something